# how to edit the taken picture with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I use Image_picker and provider and some other things to access to camera and gallery and get the photo and save it with Sqlite . there is no problem here but I want to ask is there any solution for editing photo while we take the photo using camera? for example *highlight* a part of the photo

```
  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final imageFile =
        await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 600);
    if (imageFile == null) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = File(imageFile.path);
    });
```

this is my method

should I use Image_painter or Image_editor_plus?

Comment: is it that stupid question that nobody asnwer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package in flutter, you can change the brightness using this method from image package

```
  Image image = decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
  Image brightenedImage = adjustColor(image, brightness: 0.2);
```

you can read details of this package [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/image-library.html).

Comment: How to convert this image to a file?